# Divide equation with NSPredicate (Objective C, iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here is an example how to do it with NSPredicate:

```
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1+2==3"];
    NSLog(@"%d", [p evaluateWithObject:nil]);
    p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1+2==4"];
    NSLog(@"%d", [p evaluateWithObject:nil]);
```

The first NSLog produces 1 because 1+2==3 is true; the second produces 0.

The problem is when the equation is

```
1/3==2/3
```

the statement will be true but 1/3 isn't equal to 2/3
how do I fix this?

Comment: R u using 1/3 = 2/3 or 1/3 == 2/3 ?

Answer (score 6):

1/3 and 2/3 both will have an integral value of 0.. Sp typecast hem to double/float before comparing
Try `(float)1/3 == (float)2/3 . You can calso use 1.0/3 == 2.0/3